# How to define only 4 characters input by user in C

Tags: c

I want to make program that allow user input only 4 characters. After that, the system should prompt appropriate error message to the users. How look syntax should be?
Here , i am stuck on this,doesnt know how to continue.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int i;
    char cTransID[4];
    printf("Enter 4 characters of your name: ");
    gets(cTransID);
    printf("Length of string c=%d \n",strlen(cTransID));
}
```

Comment: Never use `gets`: Even the C standard finally removed it, because it's impossible to use safely. Also, never forget that a string always needs a 0-terminator.

Comment: `gets` doesn't allow to restrict the number of input characters. Use `fgets`

Comment: Note that the string "abcd" contains 5 characters: `{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '\0'}`.

Comment: Try `char buf[4+1]; scanf("%4s", buf);`.  But re-defining your goal and using `fgets()` is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a case where the user absolutely must enter 4 characters, then you can try utilizing "getch()" along with a for loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  int i;
  char cTransID[5];

  printf("Enter 4 characters of your name: ");

  for (i = 0; i <= 3 ;i++)
   {
      cTransID[i] = getch();
      printf("%c",cTransID[i]);
   }

  printf("\n\n%s",cTransID);
  getch();
  return 0;

 }
```

Comment: This is UB.  Code needs to explicitly insure the string is properly terminated, such as `cTransID[5-1] = '\0';`.